# How can I prevent the NgZorro TreeSelect component from automatically sorting values in the tree select control?

Tags: angularjs, treeview, ng-zorro-antd

When I choose an option from the tree select, the values in the input field automatically get sorted in alphabetical order. How can I disable this behavior in the NgZorro TreeSelect component?

I have attempted to preserve the original order by overriding the NgModel and using the build method, but I haven't had any success so far. It seems that there isn't a specific method or function available to resolve this issue.